# declaration merging for react-native-elements theme

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-elements

I am using react-native-elements in my react-native application.

My app is wrapped with the ThemeProvider to pass the theme down to all components.

```
<SafeAreaProvider>
 <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
    <Loader visible={loader.loading} text={loader.message} absolute={true} />
    <RootNavigation />
  </ThemeProvider>
</SafeAreaProvider>
```

In the theme file i define the values i want to use across the app.

```
const theme = {
  colors: {
    primary: '#6A69E2',
    primaryDark: '#4747c2',
    primaryLight: 'rgba(106, 105, 226, 0.35)',
    gray: {
      dark: '#242424',
      default: '#666',
      medium: '#999',
      light: '#ccc',
      lightest: '#e7e7e7',
    },
  },
  text: {
    size: {
      small: 12,
      default: 16,
      large: 18,
      h1: 26,
      h2: 22,
      h3: 20,
    },
  },
  Text: {
    style: {
      fontSize: 16,
      color: '#242424',
      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    },
  },
  Button: {
    style: {
      borderRadius: 50,
    },
    disabledStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(106, 105, 226, 0.35)',
    },
  },
};

export default theme;
```

For the values the original theme of react-native-elements providing this is working. For example i can access the colors by using

```
const theme = useTheme()
theme.colors.primary
```

But when i want to add some new properties like primaryDark i'll get an linter error.

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'primaryDark' does not exist in type 'RecursivePartial<Colors>'.ts(2322)
```

In the doc of react-native-elements is a part about declaration merging, but i don't understand how i can archive this
https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/customization/#typescript-definitions-extending-the-default-theme.

Somebody could help me with this?

Comment: what is the linter error?

Comment: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'primaryDark' does not exist in type 'RecursivePartial<Colors>'.ts(2322)

Comment: Looks like they've just fixed it [#2964](https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/pull/2964)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, declaration merging still works. This seems like a bug on the lib's part.

Their doc says you can augment the `Color` interface in `module 'react-native-elements'`. But currently (as of 2021-04-18, with v3.3.2) that interface is actually hidden inside `module 'react-native-elements/dist/config/colors'`, not directly exposed at the top level, weird.

<del>I suggest you file an issue to their repo.</del> Never mind, someone already [filed the issue](https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/issues/2932).

Tested on my machine, following solution works.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useTheme, ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-elements'

declare module 'react-native-elements/dist/config/colors' {
  export interface Colors {
    primaryDark: string
    primaryLight: string
  }
}

const ChildComp = () => {
  const theme = useTheme()
  theme.theme.colors.primaryDark // <-- No more error 
  return <div>foobar</div>
}
```

---

Reply to OP's comment. You can augment interface however you like, as long as the augmented key doesn't exist before. For example add `foobar` key to `FullTheme`.

```
declare module 'react-native-elements' {
  export interface FullTheme {
    foobar: string
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, for color this works. But how can i merge some other properties which are not defined in FullTheme for example? If i want to have something like theme.theme.globalStyle for example

Comment: Go to this file `node_modules/react-native-elements/dist/config/theme.d.ts`. You'll see the where about of all theme related interfaces. Find them, and apply the same trick one by one. It's an unfortunate situation, I know .

Comment: Oh didn't read carefully. You wanna augment `FullTheme` itself? Same thing, augment `interface FullTheme {}` just like with `Colors`.

Comment: thats the way i tried it before but then i'll get a new error in my theme.ts for the theme => "Type [.... theme properties....] is missing the following properties from type 'FullTheme': Avatar, Accessory, Badge, BottomSheet, and 29 more."

Comment: Post more detail. I don’t see the context. Cannot guess the reason.

Comment: I declared my Theme as const theme: FullTheme = {...}. But if i remove it its working. Thx a lot :)